# How to replace previous jar files in Neo4j?

Tags: java, neo4j

I run neo4j-community-3.2.2, in which the component jar files are all saved under `/lib`. As I want to change the `neo4j-browser` to the newest version, I cloned `git@github.com:neo4j/neo4j-browser.git` and compiled the jar file by running maven. However, when I replace the original `neo4j-browser-3.0.5.jar` with `neo4j-browswer-3.1.4.jar` compiled by myself, the http service broke down while neo4j service can still run.

At the very beginning, I thought it was caused by incompatibility between different versions. But, even thought I compiled `neo4j-browser-3.0.5.jar` and replaced the original one with it, the http service didn't work either.

So, if I want to replace a jar file of some component in the directory `/lib`, what should I do?

Comment: Keep in mind that the browser is separate from the Neo4j instance. If you want to use a newer browser, just launch a newer browser locally and connect it to the remote Neo4j instance.

For example, you can do this through the Neo4j Desktop application. Start your remote (or local) community Neo4j instance. Then, in the Neo4j Desktop app, create a remote connection and fill in the connection details, then Activate and Open Browser. The browser will be using the latest version from Neo4j Desktop and will be connecting to the remote instance.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. It's my mistake for the unclear demand description. To be specific, I want to replace the pre-installed components in  released Neo4j.